# Update do texto na Notification

Tags: android, android-notification

Preciso atualizar um texto na notification bar mas não posso ficar chamando a mesma notificação pois nos testes que fiz quando chamo novamente ele pisca minha notificação.

Tenho um app que pega as coordenadas do gps e gostaria conforme estou andando ele me mostre essas coordenadas na Notificação.
No método abaixo é onde consigo pegar todas as coordenadas, gostaria de mostrar Latitude e Longitude na barra de notificação.

```
@Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    lati = location.getLatitude();
                    longi = location.getLongitude();
                    altitude = location.getAltitude();
                    precisao = location.getAccuracy();
                    time = location.getTime();
                    velocidade = location.getSpeed();

                    editTextVelo.setText(velocidade+" KM");

                    //Preciso chamar Notificação aqui dentro atualizando sempre que houver uma mudança de localização.



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // progDailog.dismiss();
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to get Location"
                    // , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

    }
```

Comment: Coloque o código do teste que fez, partindo dele será mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Comment: @ramaral coloquei, preciso ficar atualizando a barra de notificação sempre que mudar a localização. Não tem como eu ficar chamando a notificação pois ela fica piscando, quero só atualizar o texto dentro da notificação.

Answer (score 0):

A forma de actualizar uma notificação passa por usar sempre o mesmo id ao chamar `NotificationManager.notify()`.
Se a "piscar" se refere ao pequeno *icon* que aparece quando a notificação é lançada, use `NotificationManager.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)` para que ele apareça apenas na primeira vez.

Crie dois métodos, um para criar a notificação e outro para fazer o seu *update*:

```
//Notificação id
private int mNotificationId = 1;

//NotificationBuilder
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

//NotificationManager
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private void createNotificatio(){
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("Localização")
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
}

private updateNotification(String contentText) {
    mBuilder.setContentText(contentText);

    mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Chame uma primeira vez o método `createNotification()`, por exemplo no `onCreate()`.
No método `onLocationChanged()`, componha uma *string* com a latitude e longitude e chame o método `updateNotification()` com ela.